# TFS -2012 - having cumulative work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am customising our task work item. I have added time tracking fields.(Remaining Work, Completed Work and Original Work). As I transition through the states I am enforcing the rules I want.. For example when I go from In Progress to Ready for Review, I enforce that the fields Completed and Remaining are required. Also when I move from Ready for Review to FailedReview, I enforce a rule that makes the user put back in the completed and remaining work. In the transition I copy zero to both field and then add zero to the prohibited values, hence forcing them to change it..

So my question and the problem I see is that by them updating the completed again this is the new value and if a report pulls it out its not a cumulative value..

**so if I had an example of this**

Orig - 15 hours

Completed - 13 hours, Remaining 1 hours (In Progress - Ready for Review)

Completed - 1 hour, remaining 1 (Ready for Review - Failed Review)

I would like to show that completed work so far is 13 + 1 = 14.. Not just 1..

how do i total up work and enforce it with rules. From my research I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of enforcing this type of data collection, but if you must do it one way would be to have separate fields for each phase.  So Work Completed (Dev), Work Completed (Review), etc.  Then you just show the relevant field depending on the state, and can add them all together to get the cumulative.

Comment: Hi Dylan, 

not really what I am looking for, because if it fails a review, it goes back in development, and time will get logged again (work completed(dev)) so don't want it overwriting.. It looks like TFS is very limited on what it can do here. Also a simple addition that you mention, I have found no way to do that.. I have another question in relation to TFS aggregator that noone is answering lol